# Subtring with a (+) in the string

Tags: c#

i have the following string in a file

> ```
> "  14962  1250UI Iny. F.Amp. x 1 + Diluy.+ Aguja                          51890510   7798006880162B"
> ```

when i read this with this code

```
string lectura, sinuso = string.Empty;    
string baspre = @"U:\baspre.txt";
 
 FileStream fsInPre = File.OpenRead(baspre);
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsInPre, System.Text.Encoding.UTF7);

 lectura = sr.ReadLine();

 while (sr.Peek() > -1)
{
 des = lectura.Substring(10, 60).Trim();
 sinuso = lectura.Substring(70, 27);
  ....
  ....
 }
```

then i can see that Readline parse the string as

> "  14962  1250UI Iny. F.Amp. x 1  Diluy. Aguja                          51890510   7798006880162B"

because of the "+" so this is not the correct string and its short than the original so
i get the following error in the sinuso line because i cant take 27 chars

> (index and length must refer to a location within the string)

i need the exact `subtring`. How can i do that?

thx.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using UTF7?

Comment: No. What can i use UTF8 insteed?

Comment: see if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148238/c-sharp-substring-index-and-length-must-refer-to-a-location-within-the-string#answer-11148260

Comment: You should use the encoding that the file is in - if it's in UTF8, you should use UTF8. If it's UTF7, use that - but UTF7 is a *very* unusual encoding, and if you're not explicitly sure that's the file you have, it probably isn't the right encoding. But that still shouldn't matter to your problem.

Comment: I would switch to `UTF8`, it's your issue.

Comment: tnx you, UTF8 its ok.. it works..

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here but it looks like all you need is `lectura = File.ReadLines(baspre).First(); des = lectura.Substring(10, 60).Trim(); sinuso = lectura.Substring(70, 27);`. You can remove the FileStream line and everything that comes after it.

Comment: @Gabriel76 you know why you need to use `UTF8`?

Comment: No. But its work. The encoding UTF7 was interpreting the + as the concatenate.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan you should turn your comment here into an answer since it solved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string lectura, sinuso, des = string.Empty;
string baspre = @"baspre.txt";

FileStream fsInPre = File.OpenRead(baspre);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsInPre, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);



while (sr.Peek() > -1) {
    lectura = sr.ReadLine();
    des = lectura.Substring(10, 60).Trim();
    sinuso = lectura.Substring(70, 27);
    System.Console.WriteLine(des);
    System.Console.WriteLine(sinuso);
    // and beyond
}
```